# How to re-use kendoGridHeaderTemplate in kendo grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

It is possible to provide [custom templates](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/templates/#toc-header-template) for heading of columns in Kendo grid, but I didn't find any possibilities to re-use this functionality.

Link to working fork from Kendo documentation - [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emwxk6?file=app/app.component.ts)

Is it possible to extract kendoGridHeaderTemplate  to one place and use it for all column headings?

I tried to add as kendoGridToolbarTemplate and it [didn't work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emwxk6-zfe2xd?file=app/app.component.ts)

Also I tried to use ngTemplateOutlet and it [didn't work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emwxk6-h2xbta?file=app/app.component.ts) as well

Comment: What essentially are you wanting your headerTemplate to do?

Comment: Some custom logic which should be applied for all column headings. In example I added documentation version with custom template which is same for all columns. I want to know is it possible to re-use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be a way to define a header template at one place. You could however reuse the template by rendering it with ngTemplateOutlet inside the column header template:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emwxk6-juzffl?file=app/app.component.ts